# The expression doesnt evaluate to a function, so it cant be invoked

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

[image]

How can i fix this, im trying to make switch for changing theme and in login.dart i have variable isDarkMode and i want to use it to check which mode does app have to switch in main.dart

Comment: Just remove the `()`, so like `themeMode: isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light`

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a function so the parentheses not work there. Remove them.

```
themeMode: isDarkMode? ThemeMode.dark () : ThemeMode.light,
```

Comment: Thanks, i saw that a while ago